# Tensorflow : Choosing a range of columns in each row from a Tensor

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I would like to choose only particular columns in each row of a tensor, using it for an RNN

```
seq_len=[11,12,20,30] #This is the sequence length, assume 4 sequences
array=tf.ones([4,30]) #Assuming this is the array I want to index from

function(array,seq_len) #apply required function

Output=(first 11 elements from row 0, first 12 from row 2, first 20 from row 3 etc), perhaps obtained as a flat tensor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tf.sequence_mask`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sequence_mask) and [`tf.boolean_mask`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask) to get them flattened:

```
mask = tf.sequence_mask(seq_len, MAX_LENGTH)  # Replace MAX_LENGTH with the size of array on the right dimension, 30 in your case
output= tf.boolean_mask(array, mask=mask)
```

Answer (score 1):

A tensor in tensorflow can be sliced just like a numpy array and then concatenated into one tensor. Assuming you measure the sequence length from the first element.

Use [row_idx,column_idx] to slice the tensor. `slice = array[0,:]` would assign the first row to slice.

`flat_slices = tf.concat([slice,slice])` will flatten them into one tensor.

```
import tensorflow as tf

seq_len = [11,12,20,30]
array = tf.ones([4,30])

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()

    flatten = array[0,:seq_len[0]]

    for i in range(1,len(seq_len)):
        row = array[i,:seq_len[i]]
        flatten = tf.concat([flatten, row])

    print(sess.run(flatten))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I think we can use the pre-defined functions in gdelab's answer for a quick solution!